# randomly selecting 4 basic math operations

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So, in P5JS, i am trying to create a project, where I input 2 numbers and they are either randomly added, subtracted, multiplied or divided after clicking a button, could someone please show how I would write in JavaScript the code for randomly picking the 4 basic math operations and then the two numbers I inputed are either added, subtracted, multiplied or divided at random once clicking a button?

Answer (score 3):

You can put a random specifier easily:

```js
const randomOpt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
```

Then, check the `randomOpt` with a `switch` and do what you want:

```js
switch(randomOpt) {
  case 0:
    return inputValue1 + inputValue2
  case 1:
    // -
  case 2:
    // *
  case 3:
    // /
}
```

Comment: Nice! (+1) Minor caveat: if the switch is inside a function that returns (early exits) the above will work, otherwise `break` after each case will be required.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple

```
const operations = {
    '0': (num1, num2) => num1 + num2,
    '1': (num1, num2) => num1 - num2,
    '2': (num1, num2) => num1 * num2,
    '3': (num1, num2) => num1 / num2,
}
function randomOperation(num1, num2) {
    return operations[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)](num1, num2);
}
```

example

https://codepen.io/alexey-shaposhnikov/pen/MWGmaaX

Comment: hi, this is exactly what i am looking for however, is there any simpler way of writing this in javascript using random selection? Thank you

Comment: If you have an object with keys 0, 1, 2, 3, an array seems more appropriate.